# Creating embedded resource in C# class library if it doesn't exist

Tags: c#, xml, embedded-resource

I have an issue with a class library; I am preparing a library with an interface that represents a specific data storage signature. The purpose is to use the interface as a basis for implementing a number of specific classes storing configuration information in different formats (text files, xml files, etc.) while retaining the same usage profile to the application using it. I have a problem, though. In this case I am trying to embed an xml file as a resource - this file is one type of format to store configuration data. The file is located as an embedded resource in a subfolder to the project, as shown in the attached illustration.

[image]

In the following code snippet it is shown how I have implemented the functionality until now.

```
public ConfigInfoXmlSource()
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Settings.Default.CurrentConfigFile))
        FileNameAndPath = Settings.Default.CurrentConfigFile;
    else
        FileNameAndPath = DefaultConfigFileName + DefaultFileExtension;

    // Prepare XML.
    System.Reflection.Assembly a = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    Stream manifestResourceStream = 
        a.GetManifestResourceStream("TestTool.Config.Config1.xml");

    if (manifestResourceStream == null)
    {
        // ???
    }
    ...

    doc.Load(manifestResourceStream);

    ...     
}
```

In the section marked "Prepare XML" I am trying to read a stream from the embedded resource. After the reading, it is tested whether a stream was indeed created. If the file is found, the manifestResourceStream will contain the xml data - so far so good. The problem arises if the file for some reason has been accidentally deleted - in that case I want to create a new file as an embedded resource to replace the deleted file. That is supposed to happen in the conditional in the part shown as "???".

I have tried everything I could think of, searched Google for answers, etc. - to no avail.

Does anyone have a clue to how this is accomplished? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Best regards.

Comment: The premise of an embedded resource getting deleted seems ridiculous. Embedded resources are part of the DLL, and nobody should be editing the DLL. In fact, one of the reasons for embedding resources instead of delivering them as separate files is to prevent people from changing or deleting them. So why are you concerned about the possibility of the resource being deleted? I would just ignore that possibility.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a embedded resource,it is built into your binaries.It is not an physical file,rather something which is present inside the built file(dll in this case).So,once it is included,I do not think it can ever be deleted. As per my knowledge embedded resource can only be set while building your project binaries and you can not explicitly do it at runtime as it is not needed due to reasons mentioned above.

Comment: Thanks to everyone for this clarification. The visual impression from the project tree, where the resource shows up like a file, confused me.